# Help to solve linear 1st order integro-PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, integro-differential-equations

I am wondering if there are good methods (analytical, numerical) to solve equations of the form

$$
f(\mathbf{x})\frac{\partial u(\mathbf{x},t)}{\partial t} + \mathbf{a}(\mathbf{x})\cdot \nabla u(\mathbf{x},t) + b(\mathbf{x},t)u(\mathbf{x},t) + \iiint u(\mathbf{x}',t)\,d^3\mathbf{x}' = c_0
,\quad
u(\mathbf{x},t)=u_0(\mathbf{x})
,\quad
\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3
,\quad t\in[0,\infty).
$$

In the case where the integral is constant in time (thus a PDE, no more IPDE), I already found the solution using the method of characteristics. Having the integral present makes things difficult, and I am not sure whether my previous method can be extended. Good numerical methods would also be great whether or not the analytic solution can be written.